# GeoFencing alternate for geomoby

Tags: geofencing

There is a website [Geomoby](https://www.geomoby.com/) which provide services for geofence. It creates geofences on its own server and push notification when ever a user enters in that area. This API has limitations as it provides only create API while you can edit geofence using their console. I want to make a functionality in my project (Website) in which I will allow users to create geofences on website and my mobile applications get the notification. It is possible by using my own implementation but it is a lengthy procedure that I get latitude and Longitude boundaries and then pass it to phone and every update location on phone it checks the boundaries. Do you guys know any alternative or any service which provides the fencing features like Geomoby? My mobile applications are on android, iOS and windows mobile.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for something similar but didn't find anything really good. Some options are:

[arcgis](https://developers.arcgis.com/features/geotrigger-service/)

[plotprojects](https://www.plotprojects.com/geofencing/)

Anyway, finally completed implementing my own solution. Actually the work is less laborious than it seems, and the geofencing APIs both android and iOS are pretty solid (pretty accurate, actually use less battery, etc).